# Nullify listener in Fragment onDetach()?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Usually in my fragments I attach a listener in onAttach() and nullify the listener in onDetach().

Is setting the listener to null in onDetach() necessary?

Although I do it because it makes the code look more symmetric, it doesn't seem necessary since the fragment is already destroyed because onDestroyView() and onDestroy() were already called before according to the fragment's lifecycle.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think that it makes the job of the GC easier, other than that I guess you are right in that it is not strictly necessary. If you are using a lot of callbacks you might benefit from using EventBus instead https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus. Just a small piece of advice, I know I am happy to use it.

Comment: I use Otto from Square instead of EventBus from greenrobot. :)

Comment: Ok, have no experience with that one, thought that EventBus simply was an extension of Otto. Sounds as that is not the case then, with EventBus there is no need for defining callbacks.

Comment: I'm not using Otto everywhere. In the case where I have callbacks, of course I'm not using Otto. :)

Answer (score 1):

It makes sense if you want to notify the listener of an finished AsyncTask but you are not interested in the result if the Fragment is not attached anymore. In the onPostExecute you then check if the listener is still present and if so use it.

So yes, there is at least one use cases where it makes sense to set the listener to null.